# Cannot dual boot Acer Aspire V3575G

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, acer

I have an Acer Aspire V3575G with Windows 10 installed (UEFI mode) and I want to dual boot with Win 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

I've followed several tutorials, I've read a lot, I also asked my friends who already have dual-boot in similar conditions (not my PC model) and they can't do it either on my PC.

Here are the steps I've followed:

- Make a bootable USB drive using RUFUS (MBR partition or UEFI BIOS)
- Shrink my HDD to create free space to Ubuntu (50 GB, I know it's plenty enough)
- Boot from USB drive and select Install Ubuntu in Something else
- Disable Secure boot (I also did it in the BIOS, UEFI or whatever spamming F2 key)
- Created a swap partition (4GB) and ext4 partition with the free space
- Installed alongside Windows Boot Manager

The installation worked fine, without any problems. After a reboot (asked by Ubuntu installation) my PC boots on Windows, it never takes me to GRUB menu no matter what I do. Additionally, I've disabled Fast Boot, tried to change the order of bootable devices and some **BIOS/UEFI** configs (like legacy mode) and nothing.

Does anyone have a suggestion? It would be very helpful.

Comment: Acer with UEFI requires you to set UEFI password and enable trust on grub/ubuntu's .efi boot files. Make sure you have newest UEFI from Acer, some threads mention downgrading UEFI, but newer ones say newest works. Acer Trust Settings - details:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 and: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291335&p=13341757#post13341757 Also  in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Also do it again with Rufus and select the other option, GPT/UEFI. The default one will not boot in UEFI mode.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to solve this problems alongside with 2 colleagues and we didn't get anywhere. I followed the steps in the guide and now my PC starts with grub and dual boot works just fine.
Again, thanks you a lot for the support!